# RegEx, get very first match or very last match?

Tags: regex

New to RegEx, PCRE(PHP), have a basic question:

Text String I'm working with is below, text is literal

```
us%3Aks%2Cus%3Aal%2Cus%3Aok%2Cus%3Aia%2Cus%3Ala%2Cus%3Asc%2Cus%3Aut%2Cus%3Act%2Cus%3Aor%2Cus%3Atn%2Cus%3Amo%2Cus%3Aaz%2Cus%3Ain%2Cus%3Amd%2Cus%3Aco%2Cus%3Awi%2Cus%3Awa
```

1. Goal for getting the first is to get everything up to the first %2C and the first `%2C` -> `"us%3Aks%2C"`
2. Goal for getting the last is to get the the last `%2C` and everything after it. -> `"%2Cus%3Awa"`

What am I doing wrong with my attempts?

```
1. ^(.+%2C)
2. (%2C.+)$
```

Comment: `^.*?%2C|%2C(?:(?!%2C).)*$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex with a lazy match and a greedy match:

```
^(.*?%2C).+(%2C.*)$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Exco6V/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(.*?%2C)`: Match 0 or more characters followed by `%2C` (lazy match) in group #1
- `.+`: Match 1 or more of any characters (greedy match)
- `(%2C.*)`: Match `%2C` followed by 0 or more characters in group #2
- `$`: End

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of *greediness*, which controls how many characters the expression will gobble before being satisfied. So, instead of using `.+`, you could use `.*?`.
For your case (1), the expression becomes:

```
1. ^(.*?%2C)
```

For your second case, unfortunately, purely *lazy matching* will not help, but we will have to actually skip most of the string in advance, with a very greedy `.+`, so the second expression becomes something like:

```
2. .+(%2C.+)$
```